# e.target.result empty in angular cli

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-cli

I need to upload a file to my system. It always worked, but after I moved to the angular cli, it started to give trouble. Here's the code:

```
reader.onload = function(e: any) {
  var data = e.target.result;
  console.log(data);
  var result;
  var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
  var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;

  /* iterate through sheets */
  sheet_name_list.forEach( function(y) { 
    //Convert the cell value to Json
    var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[y]);
    if (roa.length > 0) {
      result = roa;
    }
  });

  result.forEach( element => {
    if (element.Permissao == "2") {
      element.Permissao = "Usuário Comum";
    } else if (element.Permissao == "1") {
      element.Permissao = "Administrador";
    }
  });

  //Get the first column first cell value;                
  _component.validationFiles(result);

};
```

In `console.log(data)`, it looks like this: **ArrayBuffer {}**

And when I call `readAsArrayBuffer(f)`, I get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: f.charCodeAt is not a function

Comment: Also `ArrayBuffer{}`,does not mean it is empty. ArrayBuffer does not show it's contents, you need a typed array like `Uint8Array` or similar to see the data the buffer contains. Use the `byteLength` property to see if it is truly empty, eg if it is 0 it has no data.

Comment: If this is the [library you are using](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx#user-content-input-type), note that the type binary option for read expects a Binary String, not an ArrayBuffer. For that you would use `array`. Might need to make a Uint8Array out of the ArrayBuffer first before passing it.